# integer variable in awk script

Tags: shell, awk

I have the following code in a shell script: to count the number of columns first (variable numCol), then plug it in the for-loop in the awk to check if all the values are all 0s in each line:

```
numCol=$(awk '{print NF}' $line | head -n 1)$
awk '{for (i=1; i<=$numCol; ++i) if($i != 0) {print;next}}' $line$
```

but, I got this error: `awk: illegal field $(), name "numCol"`

Comment: You got an answer but the shell script doesn't make sense. All you need to print lines that contain something other than zeros or spaces in awk is `awk '/[^0[:space:]]/' "$line"`, assuming `$line` contains the name of an input file as it appears to from your script.

Comment: @ed, good thought, but to be pedantic, there are other "zero" values: `printf "%s\n" 0 0.0 0e0 0e-1 | awk '$1 != 0'`

Comment: @glennjackman also a good point. He didn't say `all equal to zero` though, he said `all 0s` so I think my suggestion would work. Some sample input and expected output would tell us for sure.

Comment: I agree. Sometimes I nitpick to a fault. Just ask my wife ...

Comment: The `$` at the end of each line is puzzling; I think they should not be present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass `$numCol` shell variable to awk use `-v` option:

```
awk -v numCol=$numCol '{for (i=1; i<=numCol; ++i) if($i != 0) {print;next}}'
```

However if you show some example input/output data then we might be able to do this in one step itself.

Answer (score 2):

you messed up shell's variable and awk's varialbe

this example tells all:

```
awk -v awkVar="$shellVar" '{for(i=1;i<=awkVar;i++)...}' ...
```

Names could be different, but you should know which variable should be used in which context.